# Problem understanding event handling on the iOS device

Tags: iphone, event-handling

as the topic says I have a problem understanding the event handling.

Basically I have the following problem, I have a class that gets static calls from other classes. When such a call comes it should send a notification to other classes that listens to this.

I know there is the NSNotificationCenter, but as I see it, this works somehow the other way arround ?

Hope someone can help me out here.

-mcb

Comment: How about using **delegates**? I guess that will fit your need..

Comment: Well, actually I need to use the NSNotificationCenter because I have multiple classes that need to be notified. As I understood, delegates work only for one? let me know if I am wrong here.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The classes that want to be notified add themselves as observers for the particular notification, and the notifying class posts the notification. You got it right.

Comment: Any number of classes can **confirm** to a **delegate**. You need to **implement** the necessary methods in the class, if it confirms to a delegate.

Comment: @Simon: Terminology issue. What a class can do is *conform* to a *protocol*. The word literally means "take the shape of", which is exactly at a class that conforms to a protocol does. And in the formal delegate pattern, an object only has a single delegate. I think it's clear that @eemceebee wants the NSNotificationCenter to distribute notifications to a range of subscriber objects.

Comment: @Dan Ray: +1 Exactly.. Now I understood his problem.. Delegate wont help him..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is super easy to use.

One class says:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserverForName:@"UniqueNotificationName" 
                    object:self 
                     queue:nil 
                usingBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"I just got notified of UniqueNotificationName!");
    //whatever else you want to do when you receive this notification
}];
```

Then another class says:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center postNotificationName:@"UniqueNotificationName" 
                      object:self];
```

And ta-da! You've notified the first class that the second one fired a notification. Easy peasy.

If blocks intimidate you (they intimidated me, before I started really working with them), there's also a version of "addObserver" that takes a selector instead. Go look a the docs for how to spell that. IMO the class docs for NSNotificationCenter go in depth into the workings of the thing in a way that's unnecessary for most users, so don't worry if you go in there and it seems harder than it ought to.